# how to use distinct with multiple columns containing clause "order by" , "desc", and "Limit"

Tags: mysql, sql

- i need the latest added three values having attributeId and attribute values, but distinct wont work for both.my reqirement is mainly attributeValue but with distinct latest added attributeId. below is my query .. any solution for this ?

  ```
    SELECT DISTINCT  attributeValue 
    FROM user_trans_service_selection 
    ORDER BY uniqueId DESC LIMIT 0,3
  ```

below is my table

- uniqueId  -  attributeId  - attributeValue
- 1 - 101 - 6700
- 2 - 102 - employed
- 3 - 103 - city
- 4 - 101 - 8900
- 5 - 102 - employed
- 6 - 102- student
- 7 - 103 - town
- 8 - 103 - village

> i want result as :

- attributeId - attributeValue
- 101 - 8900
- 102 - student
- 103 - village

Answer (score 4):

kinda similar to Gordon Linoff's answer.  in sql server you dont use LIMIT

[sqlfiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/746e0/3)

```
select utss.attributeid, utss.attributeValue
from user_trans_service_selection utss 
    inner join
     (select top 3 attributeid, max(uniqueid) as maxid
      from user_trans_service_selection
      group by attributeid
      order by max(uniqueid)
     ) attr
     on attr.maxid = utss.uniqueid
```

Comment: auuhh.. it works perfectly on sql fiddler but on mysql 5.6 it gives me error do you have any idea why so happens... i assure you grammatical mistake are taken care !!

Comment: just a second...Oops top is not supported in mysql..hahha !!

Comment: nywaz i replaced it with desc and limit !!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the row that has the highest id for each attribute.  You'll need to do a join to get this:

```
select utss.attributeid, utss.attributeValue
from user_trans_service_selection utss join
     (select attributeid, max(uniqueid) as maxid
      from user_trans_service_selection
      group by attributeid
     ) attr
     on attr.maxid = utss.id
order by maxid desc
limit 0, 3
```

Comment: nope my friend this code wont work for me.. i need last three added attributevalue having different attributeId !! thats why i used desc with limit ?

Comment: @Jordon It won't work or it didn't work? I mean did you test or what? If the problem it to get the last 3 just add `order by uniqueid desc limit 3` as you already did.

Comment: it works error free but values which i want are not coming even by adding order by uniqueId desc limit 0,3 !!

Answer (score 2):

//We are going to use a GROUP BY function for this

> ```
> SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
> FROM table_name
> WHERE column_name operator value
> GROUP BY column_name
> ```

// Follow these V steps {A, B and C} to find for each [attributeId] the last added record
// {A} Find for each [attributeId] the last added record (e.g. highest [uniqueId])

> ```
> SELECT attributeId, max(uniqueId)
> FROM table_name
> GROUP BY attributeId
> ```

// {B} We are going to nest this result later in the where-clause of the final query, but first we have to get rid of [attributeId]

> ```
> SELECT uniqueId
> FROM( SELECT attributeId, max(uniqueId)
>       FROM table_name
>       GROUP BY attributeId)
> ```

// {C} Now we can create the final query and select what we need from table [table_name]. In the WHERE-clause of this query we can put a filter in place that shows the information we want for ONLY those id's we found in {B}

> ```
> SELECT uniqueId, attributeId, attributeValue
> FROM table_name
> WHERE attributeId IN (    SELECT attributeId
>               FROM(   SELECT attributeId, max(uniqueId)
>           FROM table_name
>           GROUP BY attributeId))
> ```

Comment: here is alias problem as i don't know what are you exactly going to do..please put it on sqlfiddler !!

Answer (score 0):

Finally fully working code with no errors is as under :

```
     select utss.attributeid, utss.attributeValue
     from user_trans_service_selection utss 
      inner join
     (select attributeid, max(uniqueid) as maxid
      from user_trans_service_selection
      group by attributeid
      order by max(uniqueId) desc limit 0,3
     ) attr
     on attr.maxid = utss.uniqueid
```

thanks everyone !!!